# Как пустить трафик через сертификат HTTP DEBUGGER PRO

Tags: python, c++, delphi, ssl, браузер

Задача такая, есть софт HTTP DEBUGGER PRO, когда его запускаешь, все идет через сертификат самого HTTP DEBUGGER PRO, даже проверяешь в браузере, пишет Выдан: HTTP DEBUGGER PRO, Кому: Yandex. Как сделать что бы трафик шел через этот же сертификат без включенного софта? Или же через аналогичный клиентский сертификат? Далее мне нужно софт на Delphi пустить через этот сертификат. В целом как пустить я думаю это уже в другом теме разберусь, сейчас важнее выяснить как это все работает

Comment: Надеюсь так вы поймете что это за магия с сертификатами https://yandex.ru/search/?text=mitm&lr=39 :)

Comment: смысл почти понял, а какие сертификаты тогда использует сам браузер, к примеру, тот же chrome? Я объясню для чего мне это нужно, думаю так будет яснее для чего мне это все. Смотрите без подключения к снифферу я делаю отправку запросов через софт написанный на delphi (свой), через него у меня плохой рейтинг на сайте, но если я включаю сниффер, то рейтинг меня как пользователя на сайте почему-то резко взлетает, я думаю дело в сертификате именно. Поэтому вопрос собственно и остается, как внедрить браузеру работу через мой кастомный SSL?

Comment: Никаких, все сертификаты которые использует хром - загружены в вашу систему :) win+r -> certmgr.msc и наблюдайте все сертификаты которые "может" использовать хром для проверки "надежности" сайта. Это есть корневые сертификаты. Ваши догадки врятли имеют место быть, обычно "недобросовестность" не отметается одним лишь снифером, кроме как возможно - у него свой прокси и он не на вашем ПК.

Comment: есть ли вариант заставить браузер работать по такому же принципу сертификации, но без запущенного HTTP DEBUGGER ?

Comment: Любой анализатор шифрованого трафика сделает тоже самое(например касперский антивирус так же использует свой сертификат для проверки трафика), но это не повлияет на определение вас в "недобросовестные" или ищите отличия в заголовках, или указанное вами ПО использует прокси(и соответственно использовать прокси - выход, а не мудрить с mitm) .

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я использую прокси для подключения к этому сайту (приватные мобильные), без снифера чтобы я не делал, все плохо, если запустить снифер, максимально все идеально

Comment: Я вам выше написал в чем причина, или различаются заголовки запросов или у данного софта свой прокси где и расположена закрытая часть ключа :)

Comment: честно я пытаюсь понять, но не очень могу. т.е. у http debugger есть свой прокси, через который он пересылает весь трафик? тогда вопрос, если я работаю через свои прокси в софте (мобильные), то получается обмен данными идет напрямую от меня к прокси к сайту, и ответ обратно, а с включенным снифером через к прокси, к прокси снифера, к сайту и возвращается ко мне? Если честно я сломал мозг

Comment: Заголовки даже не думайте, все это не важно, я хоть уберу все заголовки и включу снифер (он тоже покажет что их нет), но сайт все равно меня одобрит, а вот без снифера чтобы я не делал, как бы не изгалялся, он не хочет меня пускать как доверенного

Comment: т.е. везде, во всех софтах, в том числе и браузере идет подключение строго через сертификат снифера... я думаю в этом все дело, иначе не могу представить, вот серьезно

Comment: Значит вам рано представлять как работают все эти системы в реальности, что сертификат не является неким магическим свойством и как вообще работает технология MITM :) Почитайте для начала что прокси бывают не только прозрачными :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков подскажите где можно все почитать, я хочу вникнуть во всю эту систему, я хочу понять с начала и до конца в чем же отличия сертификатов что установлены на ПК от сертификатов, которые выдают доменам. Так же отличия сертификатов что используют сниферы как MITM атаки и прочее. Я хочу выяснить все максимально детально, помогите в этом, если не трудно, покидайте материал, я думаю вам проще отличить качественный материал от воды

Comment: Можете начать отсюда https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL , переходить по всем непонятным ссылкам, особенно RSA :) и прочитать наконец то про MITM не поверхностно, а подробно, читая все непонятные термины ( SSL \ RSA \ асиметричное шифрование \.... ) потому что вы досих пор этого не прочли(а это было в первом комментарии) и продолжаете спрашивать что почитать еще

Answer (score 0):

Изучил проблему, проблема оказалась в OpenSSL, к сожалению этот компонент уже сильно видимо устарел и не дает возможности для работы с некоторыми сайтами. Воспользовался TNetHTTPClient, все заработало